# Compare two lists of field names, and remove unique fields

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have 5 shapefiles in which certain fields need removing. I have a csv file with the correct shapefile name and which fields that need deleting.

I am trying to do a simple comparison of fields, and want to remove the ones not listed in the CSV.

However the print statement at the end does not tell me which fields are being deleted. This should theoretically tell me before i go ahead and delete the fields.

```
shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

scursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(csv, ["FMEextracts", "NewField"])

for fc in shapefiles:
    newfieldlist = []
    oldfieldlist = []
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fields:
        oldfieldlist.append(field.name)
        print "old fields", fc, oldfieldlist
        for srow in scursor:
            if fc == srow[0]:
                newfieldlist.append(srow[1])
                print "new fields", fc, newfieldlist

                if field.name not in newfieldlist:
                    if not field.required:
                        print "deleting", field.name,"from", fc
                        #arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field.name)


FMEextracts     NewField
NGC_CABLE.shp   ACTION_DTT
NGC_CABLE.shp   CABLE_ROUT
NGC_CABLE.shp   CABLE_SET
NGC_CABLE.shp   CABLE_TY00
NGC_CABLE.shp   CABLE_TYPE
NGC_CABLE.shp   COMMENTS
NGC_CABLE.shp   FID
NGC_CABLE.shp   GDO_GID
NGC_CABLE.shp   OPERATING_
NGC_CABLE.shp   OWNED
NGC_CABLE.shp   Shape
NGC_CABLE.shp   STATUS
NGC_CABLE.shp   TUNNEL
NGC_CABLE.shp   YEAR_OF_IN
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp FID
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp ABANDONED
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp BPD
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp DIAMETER
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp GDO_GID
```

Comment: Fancy pasting a couple of sample rows from the `.csv` file, please? Is it one `.csv` file per shapefile?

Comment: Sample added above. There is only 1 CSV with all shapefiles and corresponding field names

Comment: You need to reset your cursor. See:http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/cursor.htm

Comment: Would it be fair to say that all fields that are not in the column  `NewField` in the `.csv` file should be deleted from the shapefile `NGC_CABLE.shp`?

Comment: Yes this is correct. The "newfields" column shows the fields that should remain in the shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible to write less code for this task. Building lists and jumping back and forward will keep you in debugging forever.

My `.csv` file contents:

```
FMEextracts;NewField
NGC_CABLE.shp;ACTION_DTT
NGC_CABLE.shp;CABLE_ROUT
NGC_CABLE.shp;CABLE_SET
NGC_CABLE.shp;CABLE_TY00
NGC_CABLE.shp;CABLE_TYPE
NGC_CABLE.shp;COMMENTS
NGC_CABLE.shp;FID
NGC_CABLE.shp;GDO_GID
NGC_CABLE.shp;OPERATING_
NGC_CABLE.shp;OWNED
NGC_CABLE.shp;Shape
NGC_CABLE.shp;STATUS
NGC_CABLE.shp;TUNNEL
NGC_CABLE.shp;YEAR_OF_IN
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp;FID
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp;ABANDONED
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp;BPD
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp;DIAMETER
NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp;GDO_GID
```

ArcGIS 10.4+ solution (comes with `pandas`); you can also install `pandas` on your own:

```
import pandas as pd
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\Datasets\data_SHAPE'

shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()#['NGC_CABLE.shp', 'NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp']
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\GIS\Temp\ReferenceFields.csv", sep=';')

for shp in shps:
    print "Shapefile {}".format(shp).center(50, '-')

    fields_to_keep = list(df[df['FMEextracts'] == shp]['NewField'].values)

    for field in arcpy.ListFields(shp):
        if field.name not in fields_to_keep and not field.required:
            print "deleting the field  - ", field.name
    print
```

ArcGIS 10.x solution using the built-in Python `csv` module:

```
import csv
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\Datasets\data_SHAPE'
shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()#['NGC_CABLE.shp', 'NGC_GAS_PIPE_FEEDER.shp']

f = open(r"C:\GIS\Temp\ReferenceFields.csv")
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
data = [row for row in reader]

for shp in shps:
    print "Shapefile {}".format(shp).center(50, '-')

    fields_to_keep = [row['NewField'] for row in data if row['FMEextracts'] == shp]

    for field in arcpy.ListFields(shp):
        if field.name not in fields_to_keep and not field.required:
            print "deleting the field  - ", field.name
    print
```

Comment: Wow! What a great answer to my question. I used the Pandas method which worked great. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked for you!